# Azure standard product category

Tags: api, azure, azure-web-app-service, azureportal

Using the Usage API of the Enterprise Agreement, the MeterCategory are quite different from the categories exposed everywhere on the Azure website.

Is there anyone that knows about an API exposing the Azure products with the actual categories and category description as they exist on the Azure website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the pricing calculator page on Azure website, I found this API link: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/api/v2/pricing/categories/calculator/?culture=en-ca&discount=mosp

Which gives more information about the Azure categories:

```
"slug": "compute",
"displayName": "Compute",
"products": [{
    "slug": "virtual-machines",
    "displayName": "Virtual Machines",
    "description": "Provision Windows and Linux virtual machines in seconds",
    "keywords": "series,sql server,biztalk,instances,vm,ri,paygo,ec2,gpu,cpu,vms,sharepoint,reserved instances,nvidia",
    "pricingUrl": "/pricing/details/virtual-machines/"
},
{...}
```

I am still interested if someone has another data source.